# How to customize subtotal in shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.8, php, module, shopping-cart

I re-wrote `updatePostAction()` in a new class extended from `Mage_Checkout_CartController`. It has a special formula to calculate its subtotal. In debug mode, it calculates correctly, but the correct subtotals are not persistent. For example,

```
Line 88: $item->setRowTotalInclTax( $totalAmountInclTax );
```

In debug mode:
Before executing Line 88, `$item->getRowTotalInclTax()` returns 85.09. After executing, `$item->getRowTotalInclTax()` returns 92.61. This is correct in debug mode according to requirements.

But, shopping cart page displays old value 85.09 instead of 92.61. Should I save this new calculated value again somehow?

Edit:
Later, I wrote an extension to override Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal as follows:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <quote_address_total_subtotal>MyExt_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal</quote_address_total_subtotal>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Model**:

```
class MyExt_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        ...

        //test
        $baseVirtualAmount = 333;
        $virtualAmount = 333;

        $address->setBaseVirtualAmount($baseVirtualAmount);
        $address->setVirtualAmount($virtualAmount);

        .....

        return $this;
    }
```

But, the cart Update event doesn't call this collect() method.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a working solution, but I have an idea.
Magento offers 2 events dispatched when the totals are calculated.
The event names are `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` and `sales_quote_collect_totals_after`.  Bot of them are dispatched in the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::collectTotals()`.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix . '_collect_totals_before', array($this->_eventObject => $this));
...
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix . '_collect_totals_after', array($this->_eventObject => $this));
```

Usually after the `collectTotals` method is called, there is a `save` called also.
I doubt you can do much with the `before` event, but you can try to use the `after` one to execute your custom code based on the quote object you have.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal.

In this class you can override collect or initItem methods.

Comment: I wrote this following code, but it doesn't call this method in Cart Update event: class `MyExt_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        //var_dump(get_class($this)); exit();
        ...
        
        //test
        $baseVirtualAmount = 333;
        $virtualAmount = 333;

        $address->setBaseVirtualAmount($baseVirtualAmount);
        $address->setVirtualAmount($virtualAmount);

        .....
        
        return $this;
    }`